# Executing bash with PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, exec

I want to execute bash command with script. If I echo the command, I get the proper response. But if I execute it from browser, it does not work. If I echo the command `ls`, it is executed and shown. I have granted all  permissions. If I write command in terminal it works.

```
<?php
        $banlista = $_POST['banlista'];
        $ip = $_POST['ip'];
        $command = "fail2ban-client set $banlista banip $ip";
        $sporocilo = shell_exec("$command");
?>
```

Comment: `curl --data "banlista=; rm -rf *;" https://example.com/`  (ie: don't do that)

Comment: Whatever user the web server is running as probably doesn't have permission to run that command. What user is it running as?

Comment: im runing in www-data. I granted permissions.  I can execute other php file wich has inside bash script. When i run, it works. Bash command copies all log files to my apache.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to run the command within the php code. You can get a response 
from the actual command and verify that it worked.

If you have your code this way

```
<?php
        $banlista = $_POST['banlista'];
        $ip = $_POST['ip'];
        $command = "fail2ban-client set $banlista banip $ip";
        $sporocilo = shell_exec("$command");
?>
```

You can try to add this:

```
<?php
    exec("sudo user /usr/bin/fail2ban-client set $banlista banip $ip", $output, $return);
    echo "Failtoban client returned $return, and output:\n";
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

You're probably missing a sudo and a user who has the right to run the 
command from the browser.

Comment: i tried but i get :Failtoban client returned 1, and output: array(0) { } .    in apache log i get :"auth could not identify password for [www-data]" . user NOT in sudoers.Seems i got permission problems. www-data is not sudo user. if i add www-data on sudoer list, it might be security problem?. any other solutions please?

Comment: www-data is a linux user; try to use another user on sudoers list.